# Как обновлять данные Recyclerview

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Создал список с помощью Recyclerview. Возникла проблема. После записи данных в БД новый пункт появляется только после перезапуска приложения. Объясните пожалуйста как заставить обновляться этот список.

используя данный метод достаю данные из бд

```
    public List<CategoryList> getTodayItems() throws SQLException, ParseException {
    open();

    categoriesList = new ArrayList<>();

    String strSQL = "select category_name, category_photo, operat_date, operat_sum\n" +
                    "from source, income, operations\n" +
                    "where source._id = id_source and operations._id = id_of_transaction and operat_date LIKE '" + getCurrentDate() + "%'" + " order by operat_date DESC";
    Cursor c = database.rawQuery(strSQL, null);

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        // определяем номера столбцов по имени в выборке
        int nameIndex = c.getColumnIndex(dbHelper.COLUMN_NAME);
        int photoIndex = c.getColumnIndex(dbHelper.COLUMN_PHOTO);
        int dateIndex = c.getColumnIndex(dbHelper.COLUMN_OPERAT_DATE);
        int sumIndex = c.getColumnIndex(dbHelper.COLUMN_OPERAT_SUM);

        do {
            categoriesList.add(new CategoryList(c.getString(nameIndex), c.getInt(photoIndex), "Мои деньги", String.valueOf(c.getInt(sumIndex)), String.valueOf(makeDate(String.valueOf(c.getLong(dateIndex))))));
            // получаем значения по номерам столбцов
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "NAME = " + c.getString(nameIndex) +
                           " PHOTO = " + c.getInt(photoIndex) +
                           " DATE = " + c.getInt(dateIndex)  +
                           " SUM = " + c.getInt(sumIndex));
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    close();
    return categoriesList;
}
```

потом делаю так:

```
        categoriesListsToday = myDb.getTodayItems();

        final CategoryListAdapter adapterList = new CategoryListAdapter(categoriesListsToday, new CategoryListAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(CategoryList category) {
            //
        }
    });
    rvList.setAdapter(adapterList);
```

Comment: Adapter.notifyDataSetChange() ?

Comment: @jangorussia, может быть, не понял как это сделать, к примеру я добавляю новую информацию жму добавить и нужно выйти зайти с приложения чтоб увидеть новый добавленный элемент, или перейти в другую активити и зайти заново в активити с Recyclerview, а мне нужно после добавления сразу обновить Recyclerview и увидеть новый элемент

Comment: вам необходимо после обновления базы, добавить в список новые элементы с помощью list.addAll(elements), a потом вызвать у адаптера adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(), как писал выше jangorussia.

Comment: У тебя есть строчка кода: myRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);. В этой строчке есть экземпляр myAdapter, а у него в свою очередь есть метод notifiDateSetChange() наследуется им от абстактных предков. Если ты обновляешь адаптер, который является оберткой для доступа к набору данных, то у тебя и рекуклер перерисуется, без пересоздания активити с рекуклером

Comment: @АндроидАндроид, если я правильно понял, то при нажатии на кнопку добавить я делаю чтото вроде этого? `myDb.add(category, textView_sum, true);
                        categoriesListsToday.clear();
                        categoriesListsToday.addAll(categoriesListsToday);
                        adapterList.notifyDataSetChanged();`, если да, то почему то не помогло

Comment: я не совсем понял, зачем вы очистили список, а потом его добавили к другому?

Comment: @АндроидАндроид, я пытаюсь сделать как в этой статье `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30053610/best-way-to-update-data-with-a-recyclerview-adapter`

Comment: Покажите как вы данные из БД вытаскиваете и превращаете в список данных для ресайклера - наверняка вы просто каждый раз не обновляете данные из БД...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, обновил вопрос

Comment: @java, всё ещё остаются вопросы. После добавления данных в БД вы приведённым кодом заново из БД вытаскиваете данные?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я вас не совсем наверное понял, но я данные достаю один раз при создании фрагмента получается, поэтому при добавлении новых данных мне приходится  перейти в другой фрагмент и заново вернуться в предыдущий чтоб информация появилась, больше я нигде не достаю информацию из бд вроде

Comment: Если данные берутся из базы, то пользуйтесь `CursorLoader` вместе с `CursorAdapter`.

Comment: @java, если вы сами данные из базы снова не вытащите, то они сами и не вытащатся... Вам да - надо CursorLoader пользовать.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а как это реализовать можете подсказать?

Comment: @java, спросите лучше у Alexander Lomovskiy - я с этим дел никогда не имел)

Comment: @AlexanderLomovskiy, а как реализовать `CursorLoader ` можете подсказать?

Comment: @java посмотрите тут, надуюсь справитесь, сейчас нет времени расписывать
[стартадроид всеми любимый](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/278-urok-136-cursorloader.html),
[Три части, долго, но может поможет понять суть](http://www.nerdgrl.org/ru/programming/sqlite-contentprovider-1/),
[Туториал от Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

Поищите еще по stackoverflow, куча людей с этим сталкивалась.

Comment: ок, спасибо поищу